# Extra fields for wordpress user management in dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to add extra fields to the `Add new user` and `Edit user` pages in wordpress `admin dashboard`.

I can add this to `Edit user` using the hook `edit_user_profile`. But how to add it in `Add new user` page?

Also I want to add some extra columns to the user wp list table.

```
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consult the core code, in `/wp-admin/user-new.php` you can find two hooks:

- `user_new_form_tag` – before the existing form fields
- `user_new_form` – after the existing form fields

Answer (score 0):

If you check `/wp-admin/user-new.php` you'll see two do_action, though I never tried using any of these hooks

hook to add tags or attribute on form

```
<form method="post" name="adduser" id="adduser" class="validate" novalidate="novalidate"<?php
    /**
     * Fires inside the adduser form tag.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     */
    do_action( 'user_new_form_tag' );
?>>
```

and

```
/**
 * Fires at the end of the new user form.
 *
 * Passes a contextual string to make both types of new user forms
 * uniquely targetable. Contexts are 'add-existing-user' (Multisite),
 * and 'add-new-user' (single site and network admin).
 *
 * @since 3.7.0
 *
 * @param string $type A contextual string specifying which type of new user form the hook follows.
 */
do_action( 'user_new_form', 'add-existing-user' );
```

and

```
<?php
/** This action is documented in wp-admin/user-new.php */
do_action( 'user_new_form', 'add-new-user' );
?>
```

You might also want to check [user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) hook